# document.write issue

Tags: javascript, document.write

I inherited a piece of code that uses document.write to insert a certain div when the code is encountered.  Unfortunately, this code is causing issues in IE where the code fails.

Is there a way around this to insert a div on the page without it?  I can't make a big change since this code is currently used by many clients(it's like google adsense kind of thing).

Is there an alternative to document.write - I don't have a way to capture a div on the page since it's something plugged in by anyone.

Comment: Could you provide more information, like exactly what code fails in IE? What version of IE? There are ways around `document.write`, like using a Javascript library - say, jQuery - but in the end any JS lib uses DOM functions.

Comment: I did some more digging and this is what I found - the code doesn't always fail in IE - only in one particular site.  On other sites, it loads up just fine.  It also happened on a site that was built just in tables.

Comment: I don't understand the following sentence: "I inherited a piece of code that uses document.write to insert a certain div **when the code is encountered**." Please elaborate on that.

Comment: don't understand anything, I don't know what you are talking about, try using innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
document.getElementById('parentElementId').appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: can't do this - the element is added dynamically to a user's page,so no div is ever known to be on the page.